# Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, centos7, reverse-proxy

I have recently installed apache 2.4 plus mod_ssl I am using this apache as a proxy server and redirecting traffic to tomcat.

The issue I am facing right now is that everything works without HTTP but I do see an error when I try to access with https.

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

httpd.conf: This is I am using to redirect the traffic to my tomcat.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/example/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/example/
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything work but the site doesn't come up with HTTPS.

Comment: You only have an HTTP `<VirtualHost *:80>`, while the HTTPS would require a `<VirtualHost *:443>` with the TLS related directives `SSLEngine`, `SSLCertificateKeyFile` and `SSLCertificateFile` at minimum. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Comment: "You don't have permission to access this resource" is a different error message than "Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server"

Answer (score 0):

When it give you an error with resources permission, it is probably saying that you have change the directory's permission.

Check the directory owner

ls -l /var/www/html/

Maybe should be own by apache.

Comment: As this is a reverse proxy to Tomcat, this has nothing to do with file permissions.

Comment: I have fixed the issue my simply adding the line httpd.conf

ProxyPass /  http://0.0.0.0:8080/ABC/
ProxyPassReverse /  http://0.0.0.0:8080/ABC/

Now the issue I am facing when I login in tomcat APP it shows error 404

Type Status Report
Message

/ABC/ABC/ABCNew.jsp;jsessionid=30569F2C728FC463DDEE9645903B3AC9
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.